# Possible to force bootstrap columns to same height & vertically align divs + crossbrowser Support

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, flexbox, vertical-alignment

So, I am trying to do the following:

- Set columns in bootstrap to same height, regardless of content
- Then, vertically align to center the content within those columns
- And, make this all cross-browser compatible (min threshold for IE, 10+)

The first 2 steps are pretty easy with flexbox, but they leave out the ability for the content to look normal on IE 10+ in my browserstack tests.

Is anyone aware of how to do this? Here's a codepen of my current code that has issues on browserstack: http://codepen.io/myriad1729/pen/JRGVZO (HTML/CSS below)

You'll see it works on any modern browser, but on IE11, the 2nd column essentially appears to be pushed down a whole row, making everything look, well, not great, Bob.

I'd really appreciate if anyone has any insight here as to whether there's an easy one-stop-shop solution to this that I'm overlooking, if there's a problem in my CSS that's causing that issue on IE10/11, or if the solution is to selectively target IE10/11 and do...something.

Thanks!

CSS / HTML:

```css
// And add in pertinent Bootstrap CSS

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.itemSource {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<section class="listEntries">
  <div class="row"> <!-- Caleb -->
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2">
      <img src="http://c51e0534b271998a1a94-58706dfbc342bfcb8f938b36c845fe8a.r14.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/first-person-sharing-our-story.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
      <div class="itemSource">
        <h2><strong>George Costanza</strong> Director</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum bibendum justo, et gravida orci bibendum in. Nunc ornare nulla non eros ultrices vestibulum. Suspendisse vitae libero in ligula laoreet sodales. Vivamus in tortor et nulla euismod congue. Phasellus nec semper tellus. Sed sagittis magna id orci placerat, eget aliquet ante tincidunt. Suspendisse vitae mattis elit, in aliquam sem. Nunc efficitur finibus lorem, eu lobortis ante condimentum id. Aenean id augue ut turpis tincidunt viverra.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I use this solution for that problem**

Without JavaScript.

I found it on [**this link**](http://www.bootply.com/126437#).

```
<div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    //Your well code
</div>
```

and add this css:

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:0;
}

.row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
     margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}

.container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div,.row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
    width:100%;
}


.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.flex-grow {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
}
```

Hope this will helpfull.